# How to create a single instance "PROD" on Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm a newbie about Oracle and I just installed Oracle Database 12 c.

I lunched Oracle Enterprise Manager Express on a browser (https://localhost:5500/em) and I logged in with SYS and password.

I was about to create a tablespace but I couldn't found the "function".

On this [Oracle video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JT56VV_3OUM) on youtube I saw that I miss the "Tablespace" function under the "Storage" menu.
Reading the comments under the video I understood that I have to used a single instance "PROD", not a PDB.

I'm trying to figure out what it means and how to do it, can someone help me?

Thank you guys

Comment: `Reading the comments under the video I understood that I have to used a single instance "PROD", not a PDB` means your installation shouldn't be container database. While installing Oracle 12c there will be checkbox in one of the steps asking whether you need container database. If you have installed container database you should be able to create tablespace in PDB.

Comment: I see. Thank you